# Flutter buttons don't update anything on click

Tags: flutter

```
new MaterialButton(
                   onPressed: ()
                    {
                      yellowSelect();
                    },
                   child: new Text(game.yellowArmy.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                    shape: Border.all(color: game.isYellow ? Colors.white : Colors.black, width: 5),
                   color: Colors.yellow,
                    height: 150,
                    minWidth: 150,
                  ),

//Function called by the material button
void yellowSelect() {
    setState(() {
      if (game.isYellow){
        game.isYellow = false;
        debugPrint(game.isYellow.toString());
      }
      else if (!game.isYellow)
      {
        game.isYellow = true;
      }
      if (game.isYellow && game.isRed)
      {
        attack(game, "Yellow", "Red");
      }
      if (game.isYellow && game.isBlue)
      {
        attack(game, "Yellow", "Blue");
      }
      if (game.isYellow && game.isGreen)
      {
        attack(game, "Yellow", "Green");
      }
      for (NeutralArmy n in game.returnArr())
      {
        if (game.isYellow && n.isGray)
        {
          attack(game, "Yellow", "Gray", n);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is part of the code I am trying to use to update one of my buttons when it is clicked. It used to work perfectly fine but all of a sudden the button will not do anything on click. If need be I can post the rest of my code.

Edit: https://github.com/SVashi/game_basis is where my full code is, thank you.

Comment: Please, post the rest of your code.

Comment: Here is a link to my git repo: https://github.com/SVashi/game_basis
I think that setState() doesn't get called which is strange because it used to update my widgets just fine, but suddenly it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SchedulerBinding setState on yellowSelect() called,

```
    SchedulerBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) =>
        setState(() {
          if (game.isYellow) {
            game.isYellow = false;
            debugPrint(game.isYellow.toString());
          }
          else if (!game.isYellow) {
            game.isYellow = true;
          }
          if (game.isYellow && game.isRed) {
            attack(game, "Yellow", "Red");
          }
          if (game.isYellow && game.isBlue) {
            attack(game, "Yellow", "Blue");
          }
          if (game.isYellow && game.isGreen) {
            attack(game, "Yellow", "Green");
          }
          for (NeutralArmy n in game.returnArr()) {
            if (game.isYellow && n.isGray) {
              attack(game, "Yellow", "Gray", n);
            }
          }
        }));
```